# How to update ListView.builder in a StreamBuilder Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-futurebuilder, stream-builder

I am trying to solve the following problem.
In my app I am trying to creat an AppBar where all your friends are. The first Stream Builder is for checking if you got a new friend or lost one. Inside is another Stream Builder which is checking if the friend is in the online offline notBother or absent mode then the circle color changes. This works really well, but I want also sort this list, so that all friends who are online will get displayed before the other ones as you can see in the code. I already printed the ordert list when something has changed and this worked too, but the listview.builder wont update. I think it needs a rebuild but you cant use setState inside the Streambuilder.

```
class Avatars extends StatefulWidget {

  const Avatars({Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  AvatarsState createState() => AvatarsState();
}

class AvatarsState extends State<Avatars> {
  String? uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> fetchFriendProfiles() async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> profiles = [];
    GetInfo getInfo = GetInfo();
    await getInfo.getFriends(uid);

    if(GetInfo.documentFriends != null) {
      if (GetInfo.documentFriends!.isNotEmpty) {
        for (String friendUid in GetInfo.documentFriends!) {
          await getInfo.getProfileOther(friendUid);
          if (GetInfo.documentDataOther != null) {
            if(GetInfo.documentDataOther!.isNotEmpty) {
              Map<String, dynamic> profileData = Map.from(GetInfo.documentDataOther!);
              profileData['uid'] = friendUid;
              profiles.add(profileData);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return profiles;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, top: 25),
      height: 130,
      child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid).collection('userData').doc('friends').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
              future: fetchFriendProfiles(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  List<Map<String, dynamic>> profiles = snapshot.data!;

                  return AvatarList(profiles: profiles);
                } else {
                  return const SizedBox();
                }
              },
            );
          } else {
            return const SizedBox();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildAvatar(String name, String filename, String activity) {
    ...
  }
}

class AvatarList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> profiles;

  const AvatarList({Key? key, required this.profiles}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  AvatarListState createState() => AvatarListState();
}

class AvatarListState extends State<AvatarList> {
  void reloadAvatarList() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  void reorderProfiles(List<Map<String, dynamic>> profiles) async {
    bool stateMissing = false;

    for(Map<String, dynamic> profile in profiles) {
      if(profile["activity"] == null) {
        stateMissing = true;
      }
    }
    if(!stateMissing) {
      widget.profiles.sort((a, b) => getActivityPriority(a['activity']).compareTo(getActivityPriority(b['activity'])));
    }
  }

  int getActivityPriority(String activity) {
    switch (activity) {
      case "online":
        return 0;
      case "absent":
        return 1;
      case "notBother":
        return 2;
      case "offline":
        return 3;
      default:
        return 4;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: widget.profiles.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        String name = widget.profiles[index]['displayName'] ?? '';
        String profilePicture = widget.profiles[index]['profilePicture'] ?? '';
        String uid = widget.profiles[index]['uid'] ?? '';
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid).collection('userData').doc('activity').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              Map<String, dynamic>? data = snapshot.data?.data();
              if (data != null && data.isNotEmpty) {
                String activity = data['activity'];

                widget.profiles[index]['activity'] = activity;
                reorderProfiles(widget.profiles);

                return AvatarsState().buildAvatar(name, profilePicture, activity);
              } else {
                return const SizedBox();
              }
            } else {
              return const SizedBox();
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class GetInfo {
  static Map<String, dynamic>? documentDataOther;
  static List<String>? documentFriends;

  Future<void> getProfileOther(String? uid) async {
    DocumentReference userDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid);
    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await userDocRef.collection('userData').doc('meta').get();
    documentDataOther = documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  }

  Future<void> getFriends(String? uid) async {
    documentFriends ??= [];
    documentFriends!.clear();

    DocumentReference userDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid);
    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await userDocRef.collection('userData').doc('friends').get();

    Map<String, dynamic>? friendsData = documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?;
    if (friendsData != null && friendsData.containsKey('accepted')) {
      documentFriends = List<String>.from(friendsData['accepted']);
    }
  }
}
```

Already explained above. Do someone know how i can do this or give me a better solution for this thoughts.